# Hodge star operator independant from hermitian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hodge-theory

My problem is on the definition of the Hodge star operator on Riemann surface $S$. In general the definition of an Hodge star operator on a manifold depend of the metric but on Riemann surfaces the definitions are saying $\star dz=-id{z}$ and $\star d\overline{z}=id\overline{z}$. So I guess that there is a unique (or canonical) metric one Riemann surface? Can you explain me that or/and give me a good reference for beginner in such a subject. Thanks!

Comment: There's no canonical metric; but this is true for any *conformal* metric (i.e. any metric that can be written $\rho(z)^2 dz \overline{dz}$ for $\rho$ a smooth real function).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks, but why it does'n depend of this sort of metric, from the formula $\alpha\wedge\beta=<*\alpha,\beta>_g\omega_g$ I can't get it...

Comment: Hint: How does the inner product of 1-forms change when you rescale the metric by $\lambda$? How does the volume form change under the same rescaling?